# Best practices or tips for modules with multiple websites/stores/views

Tags: product, customer, multistore, architecture

I haven't really seen this topic covered much, but I was wondering what are some things that need to be taken into account when implementing modules when the Magento setup is using multiple websitess.

Some things I'm hoping someone can cover in addition to anything else they think would be good to know.

1. What is the best way to ensure a module is only activated per website?
2. When dealing with entities such as customers, products, and orders, what would I need to do differently than if I was only working with one website?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a broad question because ultimately it comes done to the quality of the code and the features provided by the extension. When having multiple shops in one installation that require a different code base (i.e. totally different extensions per store) it might be better to split the shops up to their own installations to prevent conflicts.

1. Turning an extension of on a certain shop can only be done on an output level by either disabling it through `System > Configuration > Advanced` and switching the scope to whatever store you want to disable on or using an enable setting in the `System > Configuration` section IF provided by the extension itself. However be aware that the code is still included in that shop so keep in mind that in the background it can potentially still influence the shop.
2. The entities you're talking about will respect store boundaries if given in the backend in a vanilla Magento installation. However a 3th party plugin might mess things up by for example not adding a store filter when retrieving a product collection. Again this depends on the quality of the extension.

Comment: 1. I had in mind using a System Configuration field to active/deactive the extension per website. However, what would be the best approach to centralize this condition in the code of the module given that the module would have your basic blocks, models, controlers, and helpers?

2. So is it just a matter of filtering the collection by the store id when working with those entities? Does anything else need to be accounted for?

Comment: for collections, indeed, a store filter is required and having an option to turn it off per storeview from sys>config would be great. If your extension doesn't have any other features you will only need to apply the above mentioned to the models and resource classes. A block is not required since exluding an extension in the layout is better done through the layout XML